# Syncing a single file and keeping N levels of folder structure

Tags: rsync

I have the following structure:

```
/Users
  /build
    /.jenkins
      /jobs
         /Job1
           config.xml
           someotherfiles.blah
         /Job2
           config.xml
           someotherfiles.blah
         /JobN
           config.xml
           someotherfiles.blah
```

I want to backup only the config.xml file to another folder keeping the folder structure the same in the new folder, but pruning away /User/build/.jenkins/jobs

My new folder would look like this:

```
backup/
  /Job1
    config.xml
  /Job2
    config.xml
  /JobN
    config.xml
```

Is this possible to do using rsync?

**Edit:** had accidentally included the *someotherfiles.blah* in the output, I actually don't want those.  All I want is the config.xml file along with the folder structure 1 level up.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
rsync -r --include=Job* --include=config.xml --exclude=* /full/path/to/Users/build/.jenkins/ backup
```

The full path is not copied to the backup directory unless you pass the `-R` option to rsync. If you include `Job*` and `config.xml` and then exclude `*` (order is important, because the first match to an include or exclude rule determines what gets copied), you end up with the structure you want. If having the explicit `Job*` pattern is too restrictive, the manual says you should be able to use the `*/` pattern:

> One solution is to ask for all directories in the hierarchy to be
>   included by using a single rule: "+ */" (put it somewhere before the "- *" rule)

See the whole INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES section of the manual page for more details.

Comment: In filter rule syntax this is: `+ config.xml` `+ */` `- *` (apply using `--filter`)

Comment: don't you want `jobs/` after `.../.jenkins/`? Won't it create a `jobs` folder under `backup` otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the folder level to start from with the `--relative` option.

From the manual:

> It is also possible to limit the amount of path information that is sent as implied directories for each path you specify. With a modern rsync on the sending side (beginning with 2.6.7), you can insert a dot and a slash into the source path, like this:
>
> ```
> rsync -avR /foo/./bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
> ```

In this example, the `--relative` option will start to create folders from the second level. On the remote:

```
/tmp
|_ bar
   |_ baz.c
```

Comment: tried, works. this is the most effective way. i wonder why nobody vote it. lucky I am the first. very useful. thank you!

Comment: For completeness, the mentioned `--relative` flag is the same as the `-R` flag in the command.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
find ./build/.jenkins/jobs/* | 
grep -i 'someotherfiles.blah' | 
cut -d / -f 5- |
rsync -v -r --exclude-from=- ./build/.jenkins/jobs/ ./output
```

In steps, this is what is happening:

```
 find ./build/.jenkins/jobs/*
```

This provides a list of the directories / files in the path specified. the output of it is

```
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job1
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job1/config.xml
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job1/someotherfiles.blah
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job2
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job2/config.xml
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job2/someotherfiles.blah
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job3
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job3/config.xml
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job3/someotherfiles.blah
```

We then pipe it to the grep command, where we can put in any pattern we want to filter on. In my example, I am grepping to exclude someotherfiles.blah

```
find ./build/.jenkins/jobs/* | 
grep -i 'someotherfiles.blah'
```

output is

```
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job1/someotherfiles.blah
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job2/someotherfiles.blah
./build/.jenkins/jobs/Job3/someotherfiles.blah
```

now rsync will take from stdin the list of patterns to exclude from its sync. It needs to have the paths relative to its src argument, however, so we cut off the first few directories from out list.

```
find ./build/.jenkins/jobs/* | 
grep -i 'someotherfiles.blah' | 
cut -d / -f 5-
```

output:

```
Job1/someotherfiles.blah
Job2/someotherfiles.blah
Job3/someotherfiles.blah
```

Now we pipe it to it rsync using the --exclude-from=- argument. This will tell it to exclude the files from stdin.

```
find ./build/.jenkins/jobs/* | 
grep -i 'someotherfiles.blah' | 
cut -d / -f 5- |
rsync -v -r --exclude-from=- ./build/.jenkins/jobs/ ./output
```

output

```
building file list ... done
Job1/
Job1/config.xml
Job2/
Job2/config.xml
Job3/
Job3/config.xml

sent 318 bytes  received 104 bytes  844.00 bytes/sec
total size is 15  speedup is 0.04
```

This solution is using grep to find a list of files to EXCLUDE from rsync. It is possible you want a grep expression to exclusively INCLUDE only certain files. You can do this too using the --include-from=- argument. There is one more change also. Here is the full code for this, which copies ONLY the config.xml files

```
find ./build/.jenkins/jobs/ | 
grep -i 'config.xml' | 
cut -d / -f 5- |
awk -F/ '{print; while(/\//) {sub("/[^/]*", ""); print}}'| 
rsync -v -r --include-from=- --exclude='*' ./build/.jenkins/jobs/ ./output
```

When you add things to the --exclude list, rsync will not search any subdirectories of the list. Clearly we don't want this since we have config.xml files in our Job1,2,3 folders! So we use awk to add to our output the parent directories that we want to search config.xml files for.

After that, we tell rsync to --include-from our stdin and exclude everything else ('*')

The paths above use relative paths, if you use absolute paths, modify the paths as necessary and make sure the -f argument in the cut commands chooses the right token number to cut up to.

anyways, save these commands up in a .sh file and you should have a handy little utility to use.

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear.  I think your solution is only working because of the relative nature of the test folder to your current directory. If you included the full path, say `/User/<user>/test/*`, I'm sure it'd replicate that entire folder structure inside `output`

Comment: ok, I don't think rsync can do all this then, you'll need to pipe some other unix commands together. I'll work on a re-answer

Comment: and for the record, no I tried full absolute path and it still worked. See edits above.

Comment: But I only want one specific file from each subdir... Not everything. So `someotherfiles.blah` shouldn't be in the output, nor any other files or subfolders other than config.xml and it's immediate parent folder

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The first part shows how to exclude specific files, while the addendum at the end shows you how to only include specific files. Sounds like the latter is what you want.

Comment: With this I should be able to get something working that suites my needs.  The only problem with your solution is I don't actually know the names of "someotherfiles.blah" so I can't really specify them in my script

Comment: So use the second version. You know the names of the files you want. so use the very last section starting with "It is possible you want a grep expression to exclusively INCLUDE only certain files"

Comment: did this answer your question or no?

Comment: I think it's almost there but it's not quite working yet.  I'm going to play around with file list that's getting piped to rsync and I'll report back

Comment: To me it seems like when you go `--execlude='*'` it really does do just that, and doesn't let the `--include-from` switch override in anyway.  My output folder is as barren as a desert

Comment: not sure what the problem is, i tested it on my system and it worked great

Comment: This is needlessly complex and will not work when the source is on a remote system and cannot adapt to changes in the directory structure. rsync's filter rules are flexible enough to handle this situation as shown in Paulo Almeida's answer.